# Flash vs Javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, accessibility, mobile-website

**Update 2:**

To add swf in web page [Swf Object 2.0](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) is most used method, which is a javascript library, so flash will be depend on availability of JavaScript.

So if javascript disabled then flash will not play.

I always heard approx [5% users in the world](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) keep JavaScript turned off.

But Adobe claims

> Flash content reaches 99% of Internet
>   viewers

http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/

Is it true even iphone, ipad and blackberry doesn't support Flash?

if it's true then if same thing we can achieve with FLASH and JavaScript , then should we go for flash (If we are not considering iphone, ipad and blackberry)?

And if we also need support on iphone, ipad and blackberry for our website/web applications, then should we never use flash?

**Update:**

Firefox's plugin

**[Noscript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/722/)** has downloaded **67,446,249** times till date

but **[Flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/433/)**  only **8,723,436** times

Is it means people dislike JavaScript more than Flash?

Comment: What's the question, then?  Either way, it depends on what you're trying to do... who is your audience...

Comment: According to http://www.riastats.com/ , at least some version of Flash is installed on about 97% of systems, so the statistic is not that misleading.

Comment: question is "if same thing we can achieve with FLASH and JavaScript , then should we go for flash? because it has wider support than javascript in desktop browsers"

Comment: If they turned off JavaScript, they probably turned off Flash.  Personally, I turn off Flash simply to have my browser respond quickly.

Comment: The biggest problem with Flash is that it's owned by Adobe.  Javascript and HTML 5 are not.

Comment: Disabling js need not prevent flash - a good developer will include `object/embed` pair in `<noscript>` tags even if he's using `SWFObject` to embed flash

Comment: Use a `<noscript></noscript>` tag in the html code (preferably right after the script tag that adds swf using SWFObject) and write the traditional object/embed tag pair inside that

Comment: @Amarghosh - But i put alternative content inside div.

Comment: This is not alternative content for flash - this is just alternative flash embed code just in case js is not available

Comment: Really... I can't imagine using the Internet without JavaScript. Enjoy refreshing the page for every action... no thanks. JavaScript is necessary for any decently complex site unless you only press one button per hour. It saves traffic and time. On the other hand, I don't have Flash installed, as the only purpose of it is to view Youtube videos.

Answer (score 11):

A few things to consider:

These days, users who disable JavaScript usually do so with a tool like [NoScript](http://noscript.net/), which also disables Flash.  That means you probably would't reach any more users by developing in Flash.

There are many new users browsing with mobile devices every day, and as you pointed out, some of the most popular ones don't support Flash at all.  Even those that support Flash often don't run it very well.  On the other hand, nearly all web-enabled devices are now being made with optimized JavaScript support.

Unlike Flash, JavaScript is not controlled by a single company.  That means many more people are working to improve its performance, reliability, and features.  Your users will benefit from this in the long run.

If you are able, JavaScript instead of Flash.

Comment: Hmm you are right. I think we should avoid Flash now , as much as possible.

Answer (score 8):

If you want mobile to work, go for Javascript. You can always politely ask your non-JS users to turn it on for your website.

Comment: If javascript is required (for something useful), most people won't mind turning it on. It's just turned off for security/abuse reasons.

Comment: @Brendan Long: JavaScript doesn't make your site any less secure... especially since you can't control if users use it or not. In fact, it can make your site **more** secure. If you just have one page with JavaScript, and maybe some premade HTML forms, you can fill in the values of nodes with variables received from RPC calls. With raw HTML, you have to generate the actual **markup**, which is always a security risk if you need to embed user data in the markup. antiparameterization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @Longpoke, what I'm saying is that *users* will turn it off for **their** security. As in, there are things sites can't do without Javascript. Also, you can't be affected by XSS if Javascript is off.

Comment: @Brendan: The only definite security you get by disabling JS is against parsing binary attacks. Even then, it's only a mitigation at best. You _can't_ be any more secure by applying client side security to a site without a total in depth analysis of the sites client side scripting. Simply disabling JS will only save you from a certain range of bugs, while possibly introducing more bugs because the site isn't intended to be run in a crippled browser or a non JS browser, or the non JS code is less tested. Subsets of XSS still happen w/o JS; injecting arbitrary markup can be just as bad as XSS...

Comment: Forgot to mention: It's up to the site owners if your account will be secure or not. You as a client have little to no control over this.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. There are a range of things that people don't like that can only be done with Javascript enabled: some XSS attacks, tracking code, completely evil Javascript (like that one that changes the page to look like a bank when you're not looking). You're right that turning it off doesn't protect you from everything, but it does protect you from **some** things. Also, if you read my first comment you'll notice that I don't think it's a big deal because *if javascript is doing something useful, people will turn it back on*.

Comment: @Brendan, Yes, I read and agree with the first point. I just don't agree with the common misconception that you magically become secure by disabling JS, this is simply not true, nothing can make you secure on the web, really, except the admin of the site. Tracking... that's another story... IP, response time, headers, browsing habbits, referrers, etc, etc, etc. Sorry for being offtopic, I just hate when people (not you, "most people") think some magic button will make them secure in the web which has no notion of security in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

From the link you posted (emphasis mine):

> Adobe® Flash® Player is the world's most pervasive software platform, used by over 2 million professionals and reaching 99% of Internet-enabled **desktops** in mature markets as well as a wide range of devices.

*A wide range of devices* do exclude iSteve mobile devices and a few others.

> And if we also need support on iphone, ipad and blackberry for our website/web applications, then should we never use flash?

As for *never*, it's a question only S.teve can answer :)

You added an accessibility tag (and asked many related questions before), so let me answer from this point of view: your website should work with or without Javascript and with or without Flash, a PDF reader, MS Office, Silverlight, with or without a mouse, images, CSS, etc

Usability will suffer from the lack of JS but your website should still work and no information should be hidden and no task should be impossible to realize: it's called graceful degradation I believe.

Flash
Flash objects should be accessible, [Adobe has a section of its site dedicated to accessibility](http://www.adobe.com/accessibility/). The object element should have an alternative at the end of object or nearby, this alternative can be another object nested and have its own alternative, etc but the last alternative should be accessible (a text, an image with alt or an HTML page). You can read about WCAG 2.0 techniques [G58: Placing a link to the alternative for time-based media immediately next to the non-text content](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G58.html), [G69: Providing an alternative for time based media](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G69.html) and many others.

JS
I've used `NoScript` for a long time and have seen more than often a common failure: using Javascript to detect Flash. That won't help.
Another one is the meaningless alternative "Get the Flash player at Adobe website". Yeah thanks, it's running fine, the only problem is with the detection script that won't run ...
So don't try to detect Flash, just put it in an object element and provide (a) meaningful alternative(s).

That will address both the 97% and 99% users, both the remaining 3% and 1% ones as well as, finally, those with Flash installed but who can only guess what unlabeled buttons in the SWF can do or worse get trapped in the Flash object while tabulating. These are blind users for the former and blind users as well as keyboard-only surfers for the second part.
From a [recent survey](http://webaim.org/blog/screen-reader-user-survey-results/), 75% of blind users keep JS running and it's unspecified for partially sighted people (probably more, keeping in mind that there are 10 times more partially sighted than blind people).

Comment: +1 thanks for good answer. I use Flash for sIFR font and for Banner in business sites because client asks for this and to embed video on page. and I think sIFR is ok to use because it degrades nicely, and currently there is not other better option to embed video with cross browser compatibility than flash. the only thing i can avoid from now, Flash banners.

Comment: Yes Flash videos are the compatible alternative to other formats, quite ironic.

Answer (score 1):

After working with both Javascript and Flash for several years, here is my perspective-

Use Flash when you need to play Video, Audio or use players, Complex Animation, 3-Dimensional draws, and complex multi-media.

Use Javascript when you need simple drop-downs, forms, popups, tooltips, accordions, tabPanels etc.

Flash is going to be there till all browsers implement the w3c standards consistently and this is the real big deal and the reason why Flash came into picture. So for most software strategies in companies, building apps needing flash is perfectly fine as most of the companies are having to build a seperate native app strategies on these IPhones and IPads.

Couple of interesting things to look out-

1. Javascript is slower on IPhone/IPad.[Test here](http://www2.webkit.org/perf/sunspider-0.9/sunspider.html) on your PC's and IPads and compare.
2. [Flash CS5 will export to HTML5 Canvas](http://www.neowin.net/news/flash-cs5-will-export-to-html5-canvas).
3. Flash Player 10.1 has significant enhancements and comes out of the box with Android 2.2.

Comment: maybe javascript would be bit slow on IPhone/IPad but it will be always faster than Flash.

Comment: Yes but as I mentioned above there are some things that you cannot simply do in Javascript.

Comment: Flash and JavaScript are based off ECMAScript. Anything you can do in Flash you can do in JavaScript. JavaScript is a full-featured programming language. It's used to create web applications, video games, particle systems, etc. Just because you're not skilled in the language, don't blame the language itself.

Answer (score 0):

Because your audience as previous stated, suggested that there is a market that flash does not penetrate (Mobile).  Because of this you would be effectively shutting out a huge amount of realistic visitors.  Just because a statistic says 99% of all web viewers that doesn't necessarily mean for your specific application audience...

Answer (score 0):

Also note that while Flash is installed in most PCs, the penetration rates by version vary - see Adobe's official [Enterprise](http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/enterprise_penetration.html) and [PC](http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/version_penetration.html) penetration rates broken down by version.

Hence, if you're attempting to write something in the latest version of Flash, the percentage of users who can actually view your content may be much less than 99%.

Also, since Javascript support is built into almost all browsers, it's only a matter of whether users want to turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

> if it's true then if same thing we can achieve with FLASH and JavaScript , then should we go for flash (If we are not considering iphone, ipad and blackberry)?

You really should consider iphone, ipad and blackberry.. even if they're not a major portion of your visitors, it's where things are moving, and you should be mindful of those platforms..

If as you say the same thing can be achieve with javascript or flash, go with JS. it'll save dev time, seo issues, running maintenance costs...

You'd be silly to start and all-flash project these days.. unless it's a really specific niche product that can only work with flash..

There's nothing wrong with a sprinkle of flash now and then, but an all-flash solution I wouldn't recommend

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask yourself of that 99%, how many have the version of Flash loaded that you would support?  It's likely that those using Internet Explorer 6 are not using the latest version of Flash.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about Flash and the iPhone iPad etc (not sure about the Blackberry). They do not, and almost certainly will not, support Flash. Apple posted an article about why they have made this decision [here](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/).

It basically boils down to battery life and application quality, according to the article. They say they are focusing mainly on standards based approaches (HTML5, javascript etc)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, where to begin? First I would challenge the party that wrote this blurb/ question to review the Adobe website for more than a Steve Jobs Fan-boy perspective on web publishing technology and RIA developement.

NVIDIA, Google (Android OS), RIM, PalmOne (now HP), Nokia, and a laundry list of OEMs have
all joined the OPEN SCREEN Project. This organization and it's various partners have all joined forces to ensure that ADOBE FLASH (10.1) and AIR (2.0) is optimized for mobile devices primarily through hardware acceleration. The iphone came out in 2007 and WOW (past tense). Now as we prepare to enter a new decade the technology that drove iphone sales is current tech (see: old news). Soon all of the Jobs-Fanboys will be the only ones without FLASH or AIR (note: WIRED ipad publication isn't FLASH, if that wasn't already obvious.)

Additionally for the record Adobe does make HTML5 tools. It was never Flash VS HTML5. To imply that you either have to choose FLASH OR HTML is just plain silly and shows how well your apple branded mind-conditioning and propaganda has over come you. I won't invest the time to address the folly you posted about JavaScript and user disabling it.

Comment: Are you somewhat affiliated with the Open Screen project?