# Designing a website in Flash or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash

So I have this project I'm working on and I'm trying to build the website part of my project. I have experience with Flash AS3, but not so much or none with JavaScript. My co-workers are telling me that they are almost the same and you can just build the site in JavaScript. But people can have JavaScript turned off, and not everyone uses Flash.

I'm having difficulty knowing what to use to build my website...by the way, this website is generally an application. It's going to have a menu with features and stuff. I figured I can probably do HTML and PHP, but there's some features I need that will be dynamic. I really want this site to be available to as many people as possible.

The only reason (again) why I would use flash is because I've used it before and it's easy to design with animations and junk.

I could use some advice.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121108/how-many-people-disable-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946840/flash-vs-javascript

Comment: if you want to target the biggest audience possible, code it in html

Answer (score 3):

This is my personal opinion, but if you can meet the needs of your application with HTML and Javascript, you will probably be much better off.  Your application will not require Flash, will likely load faster, will work better on mobile devices and will work on iDevices which do not support Flash at all.

That said, there are some challenges to building some types of applications in HTML and Javascript, particularly if you need to work across a wide range of browsers.  Using a popular library like jQuery or YUI can help with a lot of that cross browser compatibility, but some capabilities are only available in the more modern browsers.

On the opposite end of things, some things can be done better in Flash than in HTML (particularly in old browsers).

So ... the answer is that, it depends on the needs of your application.  If it were me, I'd build it in HTML and Javascript unless I found a reason that I couldn't make a successful application that way.

As for computers with Javascript off, it's my opinion that those computers are not doing modern things on the web anyway and would not likely be customers of anything I'd build on the web.  Google has dropped support for computers without javascript and some old browsers from some of their apps because the cost of development for those cases is way higher than the benefit from the few customers you might gain by it.  Whether that logic applies to your application obviously depends upon what you're doing and who it would appeal to.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking to use javascript, there is jquery which is very easy to use and very rich in functioanlity. There is also extjs which is also easy and functionality rich but its not free for commercial use.

If you are new to javascript and already know java, you can use Google web toolkit where you write the code in java and the toolkit compiles that into a javascript. But this depends on how much server functionality you have.

IF the website is a simple one, you can probably use jquery, html and css.

Answer (score 0):

If its a commercial project I would use Flash because You're good at it and You will build the app faster.
If You want to take a fascinating journey with the most popular language and develop Your skills then use javascript.

Flash and javascript are both very popular. For both methods You can use a fallback if the technology is not available.

If You decide to use javascript consider using backbone.js. It's a great MVC library.